# Jackson preprocess deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I deserialize an object, I want to do some transformation on the json (move/change/add fields) then continue processing the deserialized object. Is this possible?

**Simple example:**

**Input JSON**

```
{
    "first": "thing",
    "seconds": [ 55, 67, 12 ]
}
```

**My Object**

```
public class MyObject {
    private String new;
    private int second;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Deserializer**

```
public class MyObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode json = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        JsonNode translatedJson = translate(json);

        // continue processing MyObject like ObjectMapper#readValue would using the translated json
    }

    private JsonNode translate(final JsonNode json) {
        ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) json;

        // Update 'first' to 'new'
        object.put("new", object.get("first").asText()).remove("first");

        // Find the max in 'seconds' and add it as 'second'
        JsonNode seconds = object.get("seconds");
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < seconds.size(); i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, seconds.get(i).asInt());
        }
        object.put("second", max).remove("seconds");

        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to give an example?

Comment: unless you can alter the code of the deserialiser itself, then you'd have to deserialise it to an object, and then translate it into a different object structure using regular code.

Comment: I can alter the deserializer, but not sure the best way, see example above.

Comment: I'm at a loss what you would need this for. I'd consider it cleaner design to deserialize into an interface class, then map into your domain entity. Also, `new` is not a valid class member name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the `ObjectCodec` from the `JsonParser`:

```
public class MyObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode json = coded.readTree(p);
        JsonNode translatedJson = translate(json);

        // continue processing MyObject like ObjectMapper#readValue would using the translated json
        return codec.treeToValue(node, MyObject.class);
    }

    private JsonNode translate(final JsonNode json) {
        ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) json;

        // Update 'first' to 'new'
        object.put("new", object.get("first").asText()).remove("first");

        // Find the max in 'seconds' and add it as 'second'
        JsonNode seconds = object.get("seconds");
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < seconds.size(); i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, seconds.get(i).asInt());
        }
        object.put("second", max).remove("seconds");

        return object;
    }
}
```

Note that you won't be able to use `new` as field name in the Java class because it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I put the `@JsonDeserilize` on the object declaration where the getters/setters for `MyObject` are and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @frant.hartm : Please fix your code snippet, instead of "node" it should be "translatedJson". Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot!

Comment: I am missing something here.  How can you call codec.treeToValue() on the same class as your Deserializer is for.  @JsonDeserializer(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class).   MyObjectDeserializer:: deserialize is called then when you call codec.treeToValue(node, MyObject.class) doesnt that just call the same deserializer again for an infinite loop?

Comment: It gets me into infinite loop!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to annotate `MyObject` rather than implement a separate deserializer. Here is an example that allows you to round-trip the data from JSON to Java and back again.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"first\": \"thing\", \"seconds\": [55, 67, 12]}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyObject mo = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
    System.out.println(mo);
}

public static class MyObject {
    private final String news;
    private final List<Integer> seconds;
    private final int max;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyObject(@JsonProperty("first") String news,
                    @JsonProperty("seconds") List<Integer> seconds) {
        this.news = news;
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.max = Collections.max(seconds);
    }

    public String getNew() {
        return news;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"first\": \"" + news + "\", \"seconds\": " + seconds + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like the approach, but my actual use cases have a bit more complexity, like finding the max from with objects.