# Is it possible to declare a variable in Java, which has the same name of access modifier?

Tags: java

I would like to parse some JSON and for that I need to create a POJO class. My POJO looks like below;

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private String public;

    public String getPublic(){
        return public;
    }

    public void setPublic(String public){
        this.public = public;
    }
}
```

There is an attribute `public` in the JSON, so I have to include it here. But java is showing error because `public` is a access modifier. How can I fix this?

Comment: No it is not possible.  You cannot use a keyword as an identifier, and the modifiers are all keywords.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reserved words as names or identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423994/reserved-words-as-names-or-identifiers)

Comment: @StephenC then is there any way to parse the JSON?

Comment: If you're using something like Jackson, you can change the property name with annotations (`@JsonProperty("public") private String publicValue;`)

Comment: and if you want more control you can preprocess the json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991140/jackson-preprocess-deserialization

Comment: Strictly speaking, the problem is not in the parsing.  The problem is in the binding of the parsed JSON to a POJO.  (The old "json.org" library will have no problems parsing your JSON.)

Answer (score 0):

Public is a key word in java so you can't use public as a name for an attribute or variable. (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

You have to rename the attribute inside your POJO class. For example publicAttr or something like that.